# MYSQL multiply them sum columns fom two different tables

Tags: mysql

I need help with creating a query to return the sum of two columns that have been multiplied from two tables.

I have 3 tables

invoice with 2 columns

```
id
account_number
```

line_items with 3 columns

```
invoice_id
product_id
quantity
```

products with 3 columns

```
id
name
price
```

what i would like to do is query line_items and products tables for all matches between id in products and product_id in line_items multiply quantity in line items with price in products then get the sum for a grand total. so basicly i would have the total for an invoice. any help with this would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(price * quantity)
FROM line_items AS li INNER JOIN products AS p ON p.id = li.product_id
WHERE invoice_id = XXX
GROUP BY invoice_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer;

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/332b3/12

please ignore spelling mistakes as im in a phone